# Persist data across single app kiosk mode executions

Tags: google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode

When developing normal Chrome Apps, I use the [Chrome storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) to persist key-value pairs across sessions. This works great, and I want to do the same for a [Single App Kiosk Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled#kiosk_enabled) app to be deployed on managed Chrome devices. However, it seems that `chrome.storage.local` does not persist across executions of the app.

I wrote a [test app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosklocalstorage/pkhfdemklclaffgmpmmolajjpkcknggd) illustrating this issue. Code [here](https://github.com/jreut/kiosk-local-storage).

Comment: I'm having this same issue with a non-managed Chrome device, neither `chrome.storage.sync` or `chrome.storage.local` persist upon reboot of the device when the app is auto-launched into kiosk mode.  Any idea how to fix this without the Chrome Management Console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*note: this answer applies only to users of the Chrome Management Console*

It turns out the issue had everything to do with a setting in the Chrome Management Console. Under [Device Settings](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?pli=1&fral=1#ServiceSettings/notab=1&service=chrome+os&subtab=devicesettings), the "User Data" option should be "Do not erase all local user data." I had set it to "Erase all local user data," which wiped out my localStorage with each reboot. I didn't look at that option closely since I figured Single App Kiosk Mode existed outside of a user session, so there was no user data to erase.