# Chrome App localStorage not persisting and chrome.storage not working

Tags: javascript, webview, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I have a chrome Kiosk App which I need to save data (a few bytes as a string) between the machine turning on and off. 
But what ever I try, the localStorage seems to be wiped on restart.

When I go to chrome://inspect/#apps to inspect the Chrome App, there are no related errors in the console regarding to LocalStorage

Within Chrome in a browser, I would simply use localStorage but this does not persist when in a Kiosk App.

Example of code:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(id, temp);
window.localStorage.getItem(id);
```

Following the advice here:
[Persist data across single app kiosk mode executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763720/persist-data-across-single-app-kiosk-mode-executions)
I have a Chrome Management Licence with the following settings set but this does not seem to have made any difference (see attached JPG)

With the Kiosk App, I have the storage permission in the manifest.json

I have tried moving to chrome.storage but I get an undefined error when ever I try and do this.This error occurs when running as a Chrome App and in the browser

I have tried the solutions here but they don't work. Always get an undefined error:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/_YcOT4PcdAQ

[Chrome Management Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00up3.jpg)

---

*Added from comments:* CODE:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ 'key1': 'first', 'key2': 'second', 'key3': 'third', 'key4': 'fourth', 'key5': 'fifth' }, function() { console.debug('Settings saved'); });

<body class="trim full">
  <form id="kiosk" model="AppConfig" view="KioskView">
    <webview id="browser" src="link-to-my-website-which-calls-localstorage.com" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;"></webview>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Post the code you've used for `chrome.storage` and the exact error text.

Comment: @wOxxOm 

chrome.storage.local.set({
 'key1': 'first',
 'key2': 'second',
 'key3': 'third',
 'key4': 'fourth',
 'key5': 'fifth'
}, function() {
  console.debug('Settings saved');
 
});


error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Comment: Could the issue be that the code is called from the Chrome App via a webview?

CODE:

 <body class="trim full">
    <foam id="kiosk" model="AppConfig" view="KioskView">
       <webview id="browser" src="http://link-to-my-website-which-calls-localstorage.com" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;"></webview>
    </foam>
  </body>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two contexts for `localStorage` in a Chrome App.

1. The app's code itself. `localStorage` is [**disabled** for Chrome App code](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated). The only solution is to use `chrome.storage` API.
2. ***(Your case)*** `localStorage` inside a `<webview>`. It's designed to be temporary *by default*. If you wish for it to persist, you need to use a [webview persistent partition](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#partition).

   > If the storage partition ID starts with `persist:` (`partition="persist:googlepluswidgets"`), the webview will use a persistent storage partition available to all guests in the app with the same storage partition ID. If the ID is unset or if there is no `'persist:'` prefix, the webview will use an in-memory storage partition.

   ```
   <webview id="browser"
            src="link-to-my-website-which-calls-localstorage.com"
            style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;"
            partition="persist:browser">
   </webview>
   ```

   Do note that `chrome.storage` API will not be exposed to webview content (unless you inject a script).

Comment: I added partition="persistent:browser" but the localStorage is still lost on restart.

Comment: @Spencer That was a typo on my part, should be `persist`, not `persistent`. Reading the docs I linked would solve that.

Comment: @Spencer it would have helped if you mentioned the WebView in your original question on Google Groups, and in your opening post here.

Comment: @Mr Pablo of course it would have helped but hindsight is a wonderful thing as they say