# local storage not saving after browser closes

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, browser, local-storage

I'm using my works `sharepoint` site to host a simple site that uses `localStorage`. I've checked the `dev tools` and i can see the local storage is working, when i change site and return its still there but when I close the browser and reopen all my local storage has gone, this is the same on `Edge`, `Firefox` and `Chrome`.

Could this be something my admins have set or something in `sharepoint`? Any ideas how to workaround?

I've tried all below

```
window.localStorage.setItem('test','test');

localStorage.test2='test2';

localStorage.setItem('test3','test3');
```

Comment: Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925681/chrome-app-localstorage-not-persisting-and-chrome-storage-not-working

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, thought you were onto something, then I checked on my personal computer and it worked. So it looks like my IT dept have blocked cookies & localstorage for even whitelisted sites ☹️

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, we can use a custom list to instead of the localStorage, store the key/value in the custom list and set/read the data using REST API.

**Reference**: [SharePoint 2013: Working with REST API using jQuery Ajax](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31995.sharepoint-2013-working-with-rest-api-using-jquery-ajax.aspx)